# Create a stream of booleans

Tags: flutter, dart

I have to make an async call to SharedPreferences. It returns a boolean. I'd like to make the values returned from SharedPreferences a stream but not too sure how to do it? How can I complete the function to return a stream of booleans...

```
@override
  Stream<bool> toolTip(bool toolTip) async* {
    
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   toolTip = prefs.getBool((SchnapConfigValues.toolTipTapped) ?? false);
   
    yield* 
  }
```

Comment: use `yield toolTip;`

Comment: Thanks. .. And how would I listen to changes to the stream if tooltip is updated?

Comment: you should have a look at any state management solution like provider or getX or BLoC.

Answer (score 0):

```
@override

Stream<bool> toolTip(bool toolTip) async* { 
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
toolTip = prefs.getBool((SchnapConfigValues.toolTipTapped) ?? false);

 yield toolTip; 
}
```